# Some questions regarding set theory.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have some questions regarding set theory. They might seem unrelated to each other:

1. Are elements sets? My book on set theory takes $a\in \{a,b,c\}$, and then says $a$ (and **NOT** $\{a\}$) is a set.

Making my question more specific, the author constructs the set $\{x_1,x_2\}$ using the **Pairing Axiom**. The pairing axiom states that for any two sets $u$ and $v$, there is a set containing both $u$ and $v$. The author says let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two such sets. Then we have a set $\{x_1,x_2\}$. Fine. We may have $x_1=\{a,b\}$ and $x_2=\{c,d\}$. The author is saying that we can construct the set $\{\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\}$. But what about $\{a,b,c,d\}$? How should we construct **this** set using the pairing axiom?

1. Are all sets classes? I thought only the set of all sets is a class (as per the heirarchical construction of sets to deal with Russell's paradox).
2. The axioms of set theory are expressed in this form: $\forall t_1,t_2,\dots t_k \text{ }\exists B\text{  } \forall x(x\in B\iff$_***_*_**_$)$. My book says this is a sentence. But my book also says that *sentences are consequences of axioms*. How can an axiom then be expressed with the help of its consequence? Should it not stand independent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the usual presentation of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, everything is a set (including elements of other sets). However, this is more of a formalism than a deep statement about mathematics, so you should not worry too much about it at first. Just make sure that you realise that $\{a\}$ and $a$ are not the same object, even if they are both (in some sense) sets.

Comment: Also, you might like to think about some other examples, like: $\{a,\{a\}\}$, $\emptyset$, $\{\emptyset\}$, $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$, $\{\{\{a\}\}\}$.

Comment: The universal class is only one example of a class that cannot be a set. Classes like "the class of all groups" or "the class of all ordered pairs" must also be proper classes or one could form a universal set from the other axioms. The ordinals are another example due to a slightly trickier paradox called the Burali-Forti paradox.

Answer (score 0):

1) While $a$ is an element of the set $\{a\}$, in set theory everything (including $a$) is considered a set.

2) All sets are classes, but not every class (for example the collection of all sets not members of themselves) is a set.

3) The term **sentence** is used for any logical expression, as the one you have but you can also derive new logical sentences from other ones.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The book I am reading (Elements of Set Theory by Enderton) is the most highly recommended textbook on set theory at the undergrad level. I hope it is not sheer laziness or error that is causing the author to say $a$ is a set. Thanks for your answer it helped in clearing some of my misconceptions.

Comment: @algebraically_speaking I think I might have seen singleton sets (containing only one element) being written without braces if it's clear from the context, but wouldn't say that that is good practice.

Comment: @naslundx- Kindly take a look at the updated question. Thanks.

Comment: @algebraically_speaking The axiom of union let's you create the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$.

Comment: For (a) you are correct, $a$ is an element. But in set theory **everything** is a set. In particular the elements.

Comment: @naslundx: In most set theories both $a$ and $\{a\}$ are sets, and both elements of further sets. So your reply to 1 is misleading at the very least.

Comment: @asaf At least $a$ and $\{a\}$ are not the same sets. But i agree with you, let me rephrase my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the usual interpretation of ZF set theory, everything is a set. Your book is right: $a$ is a set; also, $a \subset \{a,b,c,d\}$ is a well-formed statement. How would you otherwise interpret for example the axiom of extensionality?

A class in ZF is usually meant to be simply a shorthand for a formula. For example, when we say something like "let $O$ be the class of ordinals" and then later in a proof write "$a \in O$", what we really mean to write, instead of "$a \in O$", is the formula expressing that $a$ is an ordinal. Obviously it is more helpful to informally think of classes as something "bigger" than sets.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine but I didn't say that $a \subset \{a,b,c,d\}$ is necessarily true

Comment: Ah, I did misread you. Sorry!